# JTable Date Filter not working the way it should

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable, date-format

I made a date filter for my `JTable`, however once I click on filter after giving the filter the from and to date, all entries in my  table disappear. My guess is that the date format doesn't fit

```
public void filterDates(Date von, Date bis) {
    System.out.println(von);
    System.out.println(bis);
    List<RowFilter<Object, Object>> filters = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object, Object>>(2);
    filters.add(RowFilter.dateFilter(ComparisonType.AFTER, von));
    filters.add(RowFilter.dateFilter(ComparisonType.BEFORE, bis));
    TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> tr2 = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(
            (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel());
    table.setRowSorter(tr2);
    tr2.setRowFilter(RowFilter.andFilter(filters));
}
```

The two other methods, used to give the filterDates method its input are:

```
private Date von() {
    String sVon = txtVon.getText();
    SimpleDateFormat f1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy");
    Date dVon = new Date();
    try {
        dVon = (Date) f1.parse(sVon);
        System.out.println(dVon);
        return dVon;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return dVon;
    }
```

AND

```
private Date bis() {
    String sBis = txtBis.getText();
    SimpleDateFormat f1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy");
    Date dBis = new Date();
      try {
        dBis = (Date) f1.parse(sBis);
        System.out.println(dBis);
        return dBis;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return dBis;
    }
}
```

And this is how the from and to date is given to the filter method:

```
if (g.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                ed.filterDates(von(), bis());
```

What it should do is filter between the two given dates von (from) and bis (to)

Comment: For better help sooner post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: You're not passing any columns to the `dateFilter` method. See the [JavaDoc of the `dateFilter` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html#dateFilter-javax.swing.RowFilter.ComparisonType-java.util.Date-int...-) : The last argument should be the *column indices* that contain the relevant date, as in `RowFilter.dateFilter(ComparisonType.AFTER, von, indexVonSpalteMitDatum)`

Comment: `g.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER` is worrisome on a number of levels

Comment: no given indices means all are considered, and since the table can have infinite length, I cannot define it

Answer (score 1):

I threw this example together which seems to work fine.

One major difference is I'm passing the `indices` to be checked...

```
filters.add(RowFilter.dateFilter(ComparisonType.AFTER, von, 2));
```

In this example, that's column number `3`

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.RowFilter.ComparisonType;
import javax.swing.RowSorter;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class TestTableSorter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTableSorter();
    }

    public TestTableSorter() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                try {
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
                    final JTable table = new JTable();
                    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(
                            new Object[][]{
                                {"A", 1, sdf.parse("12/05/2000")},
                                {"B", 2, sdf.parse("12/06/2000")},
                                {"C", 3, sdf.parse("12/07/2000")},
                                {"D", 4, sdf.parse("12/08/2000")},
                                {"E", 5, sdf.parse("12/09/2000")},
                                {"F", 1, sdf.parse("12/10/2000")},
                                {"G", 2, sdf.parse("12/11/2000")},
                                {"H", 3, sdf.parse("12/12/2000")},
                                {"I", 4, sdf.parse("12/01/1990")},
                                {"J", 5, sdf.parse("12/02/1990")},
                                {"K", 1, sdf.parse("12/03/1990")},
                                {"L", 2, sdf.parse("12/04/1995")},
                                {"M", 3, sdf.parse("12/05/1995")},
                                {"N", 4, sdf.parse("12/06/1995")},
                                {"O", 5, sdf.parse("12/07/1995")},
                                {"P", 1, sdf.parse("12/08/1980")},
                                {"Q", 2, sdf.parse("12/09/1980")},
                                {"R", 3, sdf.parse("12/10/1980")},
                                {"S", 4, sdf.parse("12/11/1980")},
                                {"T", 5, sdf.parse("12/12/1980")},
                                {"U", 1, sdf.parse("12/01/1985")},
                                {"V", 2, sdf.parse("12/02/1985")},
                                {"W", 3, sdf.parse("12/03/1985")},
                                {"X", 4, sdf.parse("12/04/1985")},
                                {"Y", 5, sdf.parse("12/05/1985")},
                                {"Z", 1, sdf.parse("12/06/1985")},},
                            new Object[]{"Name", "Number", "Date"});

                    table.setModel(model);
                    table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

                    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3));
                    panel.add(createButton(table));

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                    frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            protected JButton createButton(JTable table) {
                JButton btn = new JButton("Filter");
                btn.addActionListener(new FilterAction(table));
                return btn;
            }

        });
    }

    public class FilterAction implements ActionListener {

        private JTable table;

        public FilterAction(JTable table) {
            this.table = table;
        }

        public RowSorter<? extends TableModel> filterDates(Date von, Date bis) {
            List<RowFilter<Object, Object>> filters = new ArrayList<>(2);
            filters.add(RowFilter.dateFilter(ComparisonType.AFTER, von, 2));
            filters.add(RowFilter.dateFilter(ComparisonType.BEFORE, bis, 2));
            TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> tr2 = new TableRowSorter<>((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel());
            tr2.setRowFilter(RowFilter.andFilter(filters));
            return tr2;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            LocalDate localFrom = LocalDate.of(1995, Month.JANUARY, 1);
            LocalDate localTo = LocalDate.of(2000, Month.AUGUST, 1);

            Date from = Date.from(localFrom.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
            Date to = Date.from(localTo.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());

            RowSorter<? extends TableModel> rowSorter = filterDates(from, to);
            table.setRowSorter(rowSorter);
        }
    }
}
```

If you still continue to have issues, then you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I found out my problem is that the JTable doesnt contain a Date object, but a string as date. I cannot use a date object since it also displays time etc. which I dont want. However, the RowFilter.datefilter needs a date object

Comment: You can use a Date object, you’d use a TableCellRenderer to format it as required

Comment: Oh? Havent heard of that xD Will check it out, thanks

Comment: [How to use tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html); [Using custom renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer). It's a pretty key concept in Swing